# Django import error - bad argument to internal function

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-import

I'm making a basic time-card program. I'm getting an error while importing views from urls.py. The other files in the app (models, forms, etc) can be imported, but any call to import views returns an error I haven't seen before.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 3.3.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'timesheets')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "c:\timecards\timecards\urls.py" in <module>
  10.   url(r'^/', include('timesheets.urls')),
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  25.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "c:\timecards\timesheets\urls.py" in <module>
  2. from timesheets import views

Exception Type: SystemError at /admin/
Exception Value: ..\Objects\tupleobject.c:143: bad argument to internal function
```

My timesheets.urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from timesheets import views
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'timecards.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^timecards/', include('timecards.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.login),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login),
    url(r'^timecards/$', views.timecards), 
    url(r'^timecards/add/$', views.addcard),
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

timesheets.views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from timesheets.forms import AppointmentForm
from timesheets.models import Appointment

def login(request):
    context={'next':'/timecards/', 'username':''}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        context['username'] = ''
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                redirect('timecards')
        else:
            context['error'] ='Did not find match for username and password'
    render('login.html', context)

def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    redirect('login')

def timecards(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        redirect('login')
    employee = request.user
    timecards = Appointment.objects.get('employee_id'=employee.id)
    context = {'employee': employee, 'timecards':timecards}
    return render(request, 'timecards.html', context)

def addcard(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        redirect('login')
    employee = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            appoint = form.save(commit=False)
            appoint.employee_id = employee.id
            appoint.save()
            return redirect('timecards')
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm()
    context = {'employee': employee, 'form':form}
    return render(request,'addcards.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar issue but problem with my app, and none of the above solution worked. 
I tried running my views.py in python console and found the error in it. after i changed it worked for me.